# protocol name at run time for logging

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, cocoa

I have the following code for example:

```
@interface LOSHeadlineMetricsService : NSObject {

    id<LOSHeadlineMetricsServiceDelegate>delegate;

}
```

and the protocol looks like

```
@protocol LOSHeadlineMetricsServiceDelegate <NSObject>

- (void) serviceDidComplete;

- (void) serviceFailed;

@end
```

At run time in the client of the delegate I want to raise an exception which throws the name of the protocol "LOSHeadlineMetricsServiceDelegate" through reflection. How can I achieve that?

```
if (self.delegate == nil) {
   [NSException raise:@"NOT IMPLEMENTED" format:@"%s", Reflection(self.delegate)]
}
```

Comment: Note - the protocol only defines methods that allow the service to notify the delegate of events. Such protocol methods should be optional, not required since the service doesn't need any data from the delegate. Since the protocol should have no required methods, the service shouldn't consider it an error if there is no delegate.

Comment: Oh I didn't mean that the protocol messages don't need any data. It could return some data

Comment: The protocol methods you posted don't return any data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. The static type information of obj-c objects is thrown away during compilation. At runtime all you know is that it is an obj-c object (where "it" in this case is a property/ivar).

---

**Update:** Carl Veazey's answer indicates that the information is indeed present for protocols. And after testing, I'm seeing the same thing. However, this is wholly undocumented, and I would advise against relying on it for actual code.

Comment: But what about all of the Objective-C runtime info you can get with the various `class_` functions? Or the property details you can get with `class_getProperty`?

Comment: @rmaddy: You can ask for a given property. With the property, you can ask for attributes. These are the named things you see in parens, e.g. `readonly`. The attributes also includes the `@encode` type string of the property. Unfortunately, all obj-c objects have the exact same type string, which is `"@"`, regardless of the class or any protocols. Therefore, all object types are indistinguishable from `id` at runtime. This holds true for properties, ivars, and even method arguments/return value.

Comment: I just did a test on a delegate property and using `class_getProperty` then `property_getAttributes` gave me `type = T@"<MyViewControllerDelegate>",W,N,Vdelegate`

Comment: @rmaddy: Hooray undocumented behavior, I guess?

Answer (score 2):

You can parse it from the property attributes returned by the `property_getAttributes()` function. The type of any property can be determined by inspecting the text between the first character ([defined to be a 'T'](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjCRuntimeGuide/Articles/ocrtPropertyIntrospection.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008048-CH101)) and the first comma. For object types this text will have the format @"ClassName". `id` type properties wil only have the @ symbol, no quotes, class names, or protocol names. You could probably use an `NSScanner` fairly effectively here, or a regex, whatever your preference is.

An example program and its output:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <objc/runtime.h>

@protocol MyProtocol <NSObject>
- (void)someMethod;
@end

@interface MyObject : NSObject
@property (strong) id<MyProtocol> implementor;
@end

@implementation MyObject
@end

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

    @autoreleasepool {
        objc_property_t property = class_getProperty([MyObject class], "implementor");
        const char *propertyAttributes = property_getAttributes(property);
        NSLog(@"property attributes = %s", propertyAttributes);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Output of the program is

> `2013-03-28 16:39:17.401 PropertyReflection[56502:303] property attributes = T@"<MyProtocol>",&,V_implementor`

Now, as Kevin Ballard points out, it's prudent to note that this behavior is a contradiction of the documentation, which states that the string after the T is the `@encode` string of the property's type. When I wrote this I had assumed that was the case. However after checking, the result of `@encode(id<MyProtocol>)` is indeed simply "@", so use this at your own risk. Certainly any code to parse that string must be ready to fail gracefully, and not relied upon for mission-critical data extraction. If this information is desired more as a convenience than a hard necessity, then I think this is appropriate to move forward with.

Comment: Huzzah for undocumented behavior. I would be very nervous about relying on this functionality as long as it remains undocumented.

Comment: @KevinBallard The docs I was reading were a little light on what `@encode` is supposed to do for object types that aren't id - there aren't any examples in the [property attribute description table](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjCRuntimeGuide/Articles/ocrtPropertyIntrospection.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008048-CH101). So I just assumed that the behavior of `@encode` was doing this for protocol types, but that's not the case after all. I actually am inclined to file a documentation bug...

Comment: `@encode` is definitely poorly-documented. And technically, it may change with future OS updates, although in practice that would wreck a lot of apps and so won't happen. Pragmatically speaking, `@encode` can be relied-upon to return `@` for obj-c types.